# How can I track on which page and on which line I had modified a word document using Alfresco?

Tags: document, alfresco, alfresco-share, document-versioning

thankyou for sparing your time, I want a reliable document management system.For this purpose I think Alfresco is a good document management system. I want that who has modified that document and on which line the change has taken place in earlier versions of the documents. I just wonder can this be done? If yes then how?

Comment: what kind of document? As in, are you talking about Microsoft Word documents?

Comment: Yes MS Word Document

Comment: You can use the document comparison commands within the applications to find the difference between different versions of the document. You can also turn on "Track Changes" in the document to get you more detail on what has changed.

Comment: @OP what do you mean by "I want a reliable document management system"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use apache poi api for comparing microsoft documents using java. Below is link for same which contains same things, but that is not for alfresco its for normal java programm.

[Is there any Java API available to compare two microsoft word documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842854/is-there-any-java-api-available-to-compare-two-microsoft-word-documents)

Using apache POI api you can compare result of alfresco document version and display same in alfresco.

**Krutik Jayswal 

Alfresco Developer**

Answer (score 1):

You could use Alfresco plugin which I think meetup your requirement.
https://code.google.com/p/versions-difference-alfresco-plug-in/